# how to change username root in centos?

Tags: centos, root

The default centos username is root .So I want to change root
but i get this error message

```
#usermod -l newuser root
**usermod: user root is currently used by process 1**
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `usermod` to alter a user currently logged or having processes that are running.

You need first to create nother user.

Answer (score -1):

username are stored in /etc/passwd but there might be side effects doing this... what's your goal doing that ?

cf. : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/how-do-you-rename-root & http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/